# Remove junk applications from new computer en masse with tracking

Tags: windows, uninstall, bloatware

How do I remove those pesky junk programs typically associated with a new computer? Going through Add/Remove Programs in the control panel seems very slow as it is only allowing me to uninstall one thing at a time.

I want to speed up this process, is there an application for massively uninstalling applications?

If so, does it have an internal database that can tell you what an application is for and any complications caused by uninstalling it?

Comment: As an aside, Dell is advertising a, errr, funny feature at http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/desktops/vostrodt/ct.aspx?refid=vostrodt&s=bsd&cs=04&~tab=3: **No Unwanted Trialware** - Vostro systems can be purchased with no trialware and have less desktop clutter with fewer links and icons than competitors making your system run faster and giving you more space for your important files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use [PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/) which will detect commonly installed crapware and prompt you for which ones you want to remove. It will then run through the uninstallers for each of those. Since it will only detect from a known [list of software](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/removes), you can be safer in knowing that you probably don't need it. However, I find that some vigilance on your own part may be necessary so you don't remove some things that may be useful to you, like DVD burning software.

Comment: +1 for avoiding removal of OEM apps like DVD players and other useful stuff.

Comment: I wish I hadn't finished my task already. Sounds like this would save me some serious time and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest method?

Definitely installing Windows 7 from scratch (takes about 20 minutes) ... and the desired effect is guaranteed while uninstalling programs will most likely leave junk files on the system  which have to be cleaned up manually, never mind orphaned registry entries.

Comment: Ok I go with this one, but you have to have all drivers available!

Comment: @Ivo - You can easily backup your drivers as convenient installers with DriverMax.

Comment: More like 10 to 15 minutes with a USB thumb drive, though :)

And drivers are something that solves itself with the first visit to Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be free:

**[Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)** helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Add or Remove Programs" control panel applet.

[image]

[Their self-proclaimed benefits:](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

> **What are the benefits of using Revo Uninstaller Pro?**
>
> - Real-Time installation monitor is the most advanced and innovative
>     technology used today! This technology
>     is unique among the rest of the
>     uninstallers. That is why it offers
>     the easiest and the fastest way to
>     monitor installations, so when the
>     program is no longer needed the system
>     changes made by the installation of
>     the monitored program could be fully
>     reverted as the program has never been
>     installed before! It is so easy to use
>     that requires only 3 mouse clicks to
>     accomplish the whole process!
> - Revo Uninstaller Pro scans for leftovers with even more advanced
>     algorithms that are so precise, fast
>     and very effective in search for
>     leftovers of Windows Services,
>     Drivers, File associations, Shell
>     Extensions, COM components, Windows
>     Installer components, program settings
>     and more!
> - Forced Uninstall is very useful and powerful program removal feature that
>     is available in Revo Uninstaller Pro!
>     Even when a program is uninstalled
>     with Revo Uninstaller it could leave
>     some leftovers because of the selected
>     uninstall mode or because there is not
>     enough reliable info about the
>     uninstalled program. The user could
>     tell where the leftover files or
>     folders are, and according to that
>     info Revo Uninstaller Pro could scan
>     Windows Registry and the file system
>     for even more related leftovers.
>     Forced Uninstall gives a lot of power
>     to the user but still keeps the safety
>     of the system! It is very useful when
>     the installation is corrupted and
>     cannot continue further. Forced
>     Uninstall is the best solution when
>     you have to remove partially installed
>     programs, partially uninstalled
>     programs, and programs not listed as
>     installed at all.
> - Multi-Level backup system – guarantees that with Revo Uninstaller
>     Pro you can safely uninstall and
>     remove remnants of programs. Revo
>     Uninstaller Pro creates backups of
>     removed registry keys, values, files
>     and folders. Before each uninstall of
>     a program it creates a System Restore
>     Point. For maximum protection and
>     safety It also makes full registry
>     backup that could be used even when
>     Windows cannot start at all! You can
>     use that registry backup even when
>     some other program, virus or something
>     else has damaged the whole system.
> - Print and Export of the installed programs – Revo Uninstaller Pro let
>     you to print and/or export all details
>     of your installed programs in few
>     handy file formats. So later if you
>     need to reinstall your software
>     configuration it will be much easier
>     to find and install the right programs
>     that you like and use all the time.
> - Full native 64-bit support - Revo Uninstaller Pro takes all advantages,
>     power and speed of 64 bit Windows
>     operating systems including the latest
>     Windows 7 64-bit.
> - Revo Uninstaller gives you another 8 handy and powerful tools to clean up
>     your system - AutoRun Manager, Windows
>     Tools Manager, Junk Files Cleaner,
>     Browsers History Cleaner, Office
>     History Cleaner, Windows History
>     Cleaner, Unrecoverable Delete Tool,
>     and Evidence Remover.

If it does have to be free, [check this site for alternatives.](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/revo-uninstaller/)